# Asus VK222H not detected properly

Tags: ubuntu, monitors, intel-graphics, asus

My Asus VK222H screen is not being detected properly

(on display, it shows 'Ancor communication...' )

I was wondering if it's a drivers issue (they do not provide them for linux on https://www.asus.com/supportonly/VK222H/HelpDesk_Download/ )

any idea?

Thanks!

ps: on

- Linux Mint 20.1
- Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630

Comment: Maybe explain what the real problem is. Today you will find many rather identical products with different labels (brands) "on the outside".

Comment: https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/forums/game-ready-drivers/13/108362/ancor-communications/

Comment: @U.Windl what do yo mean by 'real problem ' ?  the screen is not detected at all (I plug it with HDMI)

Comment: thanks @terdon -- ..but they did not fix the issues, as far as I can see ...

Comment: (credits to https://www.linuxbabe.com/desktop-linux/switch-intel-nvidia-graphics-card-ubuntu  )

Comment: I deleted my 'solution' as the issues got back:
installing NVIDIA-drivers-495 fixed the issue temporary (with both Intel or NVIDIA graphics) ..but now again the screen is not detected ('hdmi no signal' message on the screen)